# How to reference existing API Gateway Authorizer in OpenApi endpoint definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I've got an AWS SAM/CloudFormation template written in JSON which contains:

1. A definition of an API Gateway API, with endpoints defined using the
   OpenAPI `DefinitionBody` format
2. A definition of an API Gateway Authorizer, defined using SAM/CF format

I'm trying to find a way to reference the Authorizer (2) for each of the endpoints (1) I wish to use the Authorizer for.

Here's the code:

**Authorizer definition:**

```
"LambdaAuthorizer":{
    "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer",
    "Properties":{
        "IdentitySource":"method.request.header.Authorization",
        "Type":"TOKEN",
        "RestApiId":{
            "Ref": "ApiName"
        },
        "AuthorizerUri": {
            "Fn::Join" : ["", ["arn:aws:apigateway:", {"Ref": "AWS::Region"}, ":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/", {"Fn::GetAtt": ["AuthLambda", "Arn"]}, "/invocations"]]
        },
        "IdentityValidationExpression": "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,32}$",
        "AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds": 300,
        "AuthorizerCredentials": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": ["LambdaAuthorizerRole", "Arn"]
        },
        "Name":"lambda-authorizer"
    }
},
```

**Endpoint definition**

```
"API": {
    "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Api",
    "Properties": {
        ...
        "DefinitionBody": {
            ...
            "paths": {
                "/endpoint": {
                    "post": {
                        "responses": {
                            "200": {
                                "description": "200 response"
                            }
                        },
                        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                            "uri": {
                                "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${AuthLambda.Arn}/invocations"
                            },
                            "responses": {
                                "default": {
                                    "statusCode": "200",
                                    "contentHandling": "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
                                }
                            },
                            "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
                            "httpMethod": "POST",
                            "contentHandling": "CONVERT_TO_TEXT",
                            "type": "aws_proxy"
                        },
                        "security" : [{
                            "NAME OF OPEN API SECURITY DEFINITION":[] // Can I reference my existing Authorizer?
                        }]
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I've found the OpenAPI `security` property, which according to the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-authorizer.html) is used as a reference to a `securityDefinitions` where the Authorizer can be defined.

But I've *already got* my Authorizer defined in CloudFormation JSON. Can't I reference that instead?

Comment: Did you create LambdaAuthorizer under APIs->Authorizers in aws console?

Comment: No, it was created from the definition in my SAM/CF template

Comment: When you deploy your template do you see LambdaAuthorizer under APIs->Authorizers in aws console? if you like I can show you an example using CognitoAuthorizer and the security property

Comment: Well, if I deploy without the `"security":[{...}]` declaration in the OpenAPI endpoints bit, then yes, the Authorizer is created as expected and can be seen in the console. When I include my `"security":[{...}]` declaration the Authorizer disappears - I suspect being overwritten because the OpenAPI declaration trumps the CF Template declaration.

PS - I've already solved this for my use case by re-writing the Authorizer into the OpenAPI API gateway definition, but I'm still curious to know if what I tried to do earlier is possible...

Comment: In yaml it looks like that: 
post:
       security:
              - MyCognitoAuth: []

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway does not allow you to directly reference an existing Authorizer ID in the OpenAPI `paths`. However, there is a workaround. You can provide a `securitySchemes` definition. The format of `securitySchemes` will vary between OpenAPI 2.0 (aka Swagger) and OpenAPI 3.0 ([documentation here](https://swagger.io/specification/#security-scheme-object)).

Make sure that the details of the `securitySchemes` exactly match the existing API Authorizer. **If everything matches, then API Gateway will use the existing Authorizer**. If there are differences, then it will create a new Authorizer or overwrite the existing one. Ensure the following:

1. the security scheme object name is the same as the Authorizer name. In this case it is `"lambda-authorizer"`
2. type is `"apiKey"` for lambda authorizers
3. name is the HTTP header you're using for authorization (typically the `"Authorization"` header)
4. x-amazon-apigateway-authtype is `"custom"` for lambda authorizers
5. x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer has the correct type (`"request"` or `"token"`), the correct uri, ttl, and identity source

I've tested this with a regional REST API, so it may behave differently for other API Gateway types. The example below is a simplified version of the AWS PetStore example API.

```
{
  "openapi" : "3.0.1",
  "info" : {
    "description" : "Your first API with Amazon API Gateway. This is a sample API that integrates via HTTP with our demo Pet Store endpoints",
    "version" : "1",
    "title" : "PetStore"
  },
  ...
  "paths" : {
    "/pets" : {
      "get" : {
        ...
        "security" : [ {
          "lambda-authorizer" : [ ]
        } ],
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration" : {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components" : {
    "schemas" : {
      ...
    },
    "securitySchemes" : {
      "lambda-authorizer" : {
        "type" : "apiKey",
        "name" : "Authorization",
        "in" : "header",
        "x-amazon-apigateway-authtype" : "custom",
        "x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer" : {
          "type" : "request",
          "authorizerUri" : "arn:aws:apigateway:${region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambda_authorizer_arn}/invocations",
          "authorizerResultTtlInSeconds" : 300,
          "identitySource" : "method.request.header.Authorization"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, you'd have to replace `${region}` with your API Gateway region and `${lambdaauthorizer_arn}` with the full ARN of your lambda function. The full string will look like this: `arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:lambda-authorizer-function/invocations`

**TL;DR**: If you want to use an existing Authorizer, you have to fully define it in the OpenAPI file.